# Retrieving Data from Firebase Realtime DB

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This my Firebase database:

[image: Firebase]

This is my code for retrieving data in to list view, I want to get all data from Tehsil_hin and Tid with specific id in two different arraylist.

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Tehsil");

     Query query = myRef.orderByChild("DID").equalTo(did);
     query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
     {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) 
        {
            areas.add(snapshot.child("Tehsil_Hin").getValue(String.class));
            areasid.add(snapshot.child("TID").getValue(int.class));

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    //System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

I'm not reciving data from that

Comment: Shouldn't it be `postSnapshot.child("Tehsil_Hin")` instead of `snapshot.child("Tehsil_Hin")`?

Comment: Use this for reference : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#ordering-by-a-specified-child-key

Comment: @KENdi could you please not approve an edit that doesn't fix everything (like the spelling in the title) and even adds a couple more spelling mistakes.

Comment: Hey @user3857903, do mark the answer as correct, as this helps people on stack overflow with similar questions, and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're never notifying an adapter that data was updated, so no listview will get updated

You need to notify an adapter outside the loop, assuming the loop is in fact entered (please add log statements to debug further)

You should also keep the error method body uncomment because that also is an area where you're not seeing anything happening

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the data from those children nodes, instead of using `query` you can just use `DatabaseReference` and using `orderByChild()` and `equalTo()` can access the data which only has the value you want.

In code it looks something like this:

```java
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Tehsil");

// specificTID is the value which you want to compare to the value stored in database

rootRef.orderByChild("TID").equalTo(specificTID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                          // use array1.add to store value in your arrayList

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Now you have to update the value to the `ArrayAdapter` and set it up to your `listView` to be able to display the data.

```java
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Main2Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can do this with both of your children and store the values in different arrays. You can also use different `listViews` to display the data.